# Can non-Muslims enter a Mosque or prayer room?

Tags: non-muslim, masjid

Are non-Muslims allowed to enter a prayer room and pray? I am asking this because I have seen non-Muslims come into a Muslim prayer room before.

Comment: I am trying to promote this site.

http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/124/how-do-we-promote-our-site

Answer (score 1):

I do not consider myself Muslim, yet I have visited a [Mosque](http://www.iccleveland.org/).  I was well received and we discussed beliefs.  I found it educational, fun, and I made new friends.  However I did feel like there was an 800 pound gorilla in the room that we were all avoiding.

IMHO, I feel that interfaith friendships are very important and should be explored.

Comment: I've visited the Sultanahmet Mosque in Istanbul. But that was as a tourist. (They're used to tourists, and even provide clothes for them to cover up with (I brought my own).) On the same trip, I visited a Greek Orthodox monastery in the Meteora and St Peter's in the Vatican. The Vatican was the only one that didn't provide clothes for tourists.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question and most people always wonder and many non Muslims always ask *hey buddy, can I come into the Mosque? Will they let me in?*

There might be some common confusion in regards with this....

> O you who believe (in Allah's Oneness and in His Messenger (Muhammad SAW)! **Verily, the Mushrikun** (polytheists, pagans, idolaters, disbelievers in the Oneness of Allah, and in the Message of Muhammad SAW) **are Najasun (impure)**. **So let them not come near Al-Masjid-al-Haram (at Makkah)** after this year, and if you fear poverty, Allah will enrich you if He will, out of His Bounty. Surely, Allah is All-Knowing, All-Wise. (Qur'an 9:28)

So, does that mean we should not allow the Mushrik even into our normal local mosques too, or is the restriction only on Al-Masjid-al-Haram? Well, I think it is **only** talking about Al-Masjid-al-Haram and not in general any mosque. And moreover, I don't remember any verses prohibiting the Non Muslims from entering any house of Allah in general.

And also here are some of the supporting points towards allowance of non Muslims to mosques in general.

1. They might simply be curious and wanna taste the mosques.
2. They really want to start believing in Allah and wanna pray there.

First, if the person is curious as in [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/643/can-non-muslims-enter-a-mosque-or-prayer-room#comment4181_1829) and if he stays within limits (not planning a terror attack), it is fine. It is just an opportunity for him to explore Islam. (in little baby steps of course).

Second, clearly, the person is exploring Islam and there is no problem in allowing him to explore a piece of Islam.

Finally, here is a complete supporting answer for the question "[Is the joining of a non-Muslim in a jama'a salat allowed?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/708/is-the-joining-of-a-non-muslim-in-a-jamaa-salat-allowed?lq=1). And the answer which we get is 'Yes' to your question too "Are non-Muslims allowed to enter a prayer room **and pray?**"

For verily, we must always make sure this condition is satisfied at any cost always,

> And the mosques are for Allah (Alone), so invoke not anyone along with Allah. (Qur'an 72:18)

And make sure the non Muslims don't come to Mosque to invoke others besides Allah.

If the above conditions are met, then I see no problem in allowing a Non Muslim to a mosque.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: [Here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/21559/11938) is point revisited of harming the Mosques, hence we should be careful in allowing them...