# Why non-muslims are not allowed in mecca

Tags: islamic-philosophy, masjid-al-haram

I really didn't find a satisfactory answer to this question.

Isn't the house of god should be open to everyone?

Comment: Mecca isn't the house of God and no the house of God is open to believing people only. Also see [Are non-Muslims allowed to visit Mecca?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25499/13438) and [Why were Jews allowed to live in Yemen?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29837/13438)

Answer (score 1):

Simply because, it is a sacred place where God has allowed only Muslims in Makkah, and not pagans. There’s a narration about this. A story begins when the Prophet is about to die, he’s last words was the curse for pagans, and he also expelled all of-’em from Makkah, and now Makkah has become a sanctuary, a Holy place. And because, also prophet Muhammad expelled all of them. That is why. This is already mentioned in Quran.

You can see in [**here,**](https://www.thoughtco.com/makkah-muslims-only-2004315) that God states, ”Oh you who believe! Truly the idolaters are unclean; so let them not, after this year, approach the Sacred Mosque. ..." **(9:28)**. If you’re not satisfied yet, please [**check in here**](https://wikitravel.org/en/Mecca), even in [**here**](https://lifeinsaudiarabia.net/blog/2014/10/01/punishment-for-non-muslims-for-entering/) it says no none Muslims in Makkah as it is the holiest place in the world, and it is the decision made by God. And also in [**Islamqa**](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/17535) says clearly ”no none Muslims in Makkah.

This only revelation, I didn't find any narration that prohibits the entry of none Muslims in Makkah.