# Did the prophet ban other religious buildings in Islamic countries?

Tags: hadith, non-muslim

Many Non Muslims are upset with the fact that you can’t build Churches etc in Saudi or other Muslim countries. Did the prophet ban building churches etc. in Muslim lands and please provide Hadith if possible?

Comment: Wherever Muslims have the leadership new Non-Muslim worship places are not allowed at least this seems to be the view of many scholars as to your question it has answers on the site I'd say at least I've addressed twice this topic (see for example [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29837/why-were-jews-allowed-to-live-in-yemen/30307#30307)).

Comment: Explicit ahadith on this are weak in their chain, however they are corroborated by reports from the sahaba and tabi'een and what has been accepted and adopted by the Muslims in practice.