# Is it allowed for a Jew to pray in mosques?

Tags: sharia, salat, masjid, jews

I read somewhere that Jews can pray in  mosques according to their rabbis but not in churches as churches according to their rabbis are places of Idolatry , but does Islam allow a Jew to pray in Muslim mosque and are there such examples in Muslim history?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26328/jews-allowed-to-pray-and-join-muslim-congregation-in-mosques-and-experiences

Comment: Presumably the rabbis you are alluding  to allow Jews to pray _Jewish_ prayers in a mosque, so I don't know how it's relevant to this question.

Comment: ok thats my addition to the question for a case when a Jew wants to experience the islamic prayers

Comment: I'm just saying the introductory part is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Mosques are not in the ownership of any person, rather they belong to Allah. No one may stop a person from entering the mosque; Allah says in the Quran:

"And [He revealed] that the masjids are for Allah" [72:18; http://quran.com/72]

However, if it is conceived that people will bring harm to the mosque or Muslims, then such people should be prevented because there is greater harm in allowing them to enter.

Aside from that, no one may be prevented from entering the mosque.

Anyone and everyone is welcome to come, and pray, if they wish.

However, it is a fundamental aspect of Islamic belief that no act of worship is rewarded unless it is done in the state of Iman (having faith in Allah and his Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him)).